# Ошибка: Parse error : syntax error, unexpected '!' in E:\xampp\htdocs\board\load.php on line 9 Код в основной части. Помогите найти саму ошибку

Tags: php, if

```
if (!isset($_POST['city']) || !isset($_POST['cost']) || !isset($_POST['cost_']) || !isset($_POST['pers']) || !isset($_POST['mrom']) || !isset($_POST['type']) || !isset($_POST['dist']) || !isset($_POST['where']) || !is_numeric($_POST['cost']) || !is_numeric($_POST['cost_']) || !is_numeric($_POST['pers']) || !is_numeric($_POST['mrom']) || !is_numeric($_POST['type']) || !is_numeric($_POST['dist']) !is_numeric($_POST['where']) || $_POST['cost'] < 0 || $_POST['cost_'] < 0 || $_POST['pers'] < 1 || $_POST['mrom'] < 1 || $_POST['type'] < 0 || $_POST['type'] > 2 || $_POST['dist'] < 1 || $_POST['where'] < 0 || $_POST['where'] > 3){
```

Comment: Дай нормальный пример, а не такой кусок что бы нечего не было понятно.

Comment: Это всё 9 строка!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О да, я нашел этот кусок, у вас:

```
!is_numeric($_POST['dist']) !is_numeric($_POST['where'])
```

А надо так:

```
!is_numeric($_POST['dist']) || !is_numeric($_POST['where'])
```

Comment: Спасибо))) Ты самый внимательный XD (я 10 раз пересматривал код , но не мог найти ошибки)